# How to read a 104 MB Conner hard drive from 1990

Tags: hard-disk, ide

I am trying to get text files from an old 386SX computer running PCDOS 5.0. I believe the file system is FAT16.

The hard drive specifications are:

```
Conner Peripherals MODEL (CFS SERIES) CP3104 
100 MB
CYL      776
HDS        8
SECT      33
WPCOMP     0
LZONE    776
Type     IDE
```

Its formatted capacity 104.9 MB
and it works fine in the original machine. See pic below. The floppy drive is broken so I put the hard drive in a USB enclosure.

Windows says the drive is unformatted and wants to format it, so I tried Linux.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
```

`usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=152d ProdID=2338 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=JMicron
S:  Product=USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
S:  SerialNumber=220000000000
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

`dmesg | grep -i usb`:

```
[  940.875536] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  973.289744] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  973.440121] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  973.440125] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  973.440127] usb 3-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[  973.440128] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  973.440130] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 220000000000
[  973.442645] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  973.443011] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
```

`dmesg | grep -i sd`:

```
[  974.451623] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  974.452194] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  974.452766] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Using 0xffffffff as device size
[  974.452772] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4294967296 512-byte logical blocks: (2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)
[  974.453266] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  974.453269] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
[  974.453823] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  974.453829] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  974.478116] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  974.478601] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Using 0xffffffff as device size
[  974.480070] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  974.480073] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  974.480074] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  974.480076] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  974.480078] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  974.480082] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[  974.480576] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  974.480577] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  974.480578] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  974.480579] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  974.480580] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  974.480582] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[  974.481158] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  974.481160] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  974.481161] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  974.481162] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
```

It seems the drive is sda but I can't seem to mount it. How can this be done without a recognized partition?

[image: screen capture disk parameters]

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski `sda` vs. `hda` is determined by the driver that picked it up. `hda` was for the old PATA driver. Those names haven't been used since PATA support was rewritten on top of the SCSI infrastructure to match the SATA support and it has never been used for drives connected over USB bridges as far as I can remember. (That's what the `s` in `sda` is. The SCSI layer that SATA, PATA, and USB all go through now.)

Comment: Your problem seems to be the USB enclosure identifiying the disk properly. From the Linux log we can see that READ CAPACITY returns a huge number (and that is produced by the USB adapter in the enclosure, not the driver in Linux). Maybe try another adapter. Linux can't fix broken hardware.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me that USB enclosures are as mercurial as enclosure-less USB converter cables. If I didn't have access to a closet full of Windows XP-era machines with onboard PATA controllers (spare parts for my retro-hobby corner), the first thing I'd probably try is using one of those PATA-SATA converters that advertise being able to operate in either direction and seeing if the motherboard's SATA controller has better luck.

Comment: What kind of diagnostics are running there, by the way?

Comment: The diagnostic was on the machine but I think the information comes from the BIOS.  The drive identifies itself to dmesg but evidently can't give parameters.  In response to a question about hard coded BIOS geometries https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13513/hard-coded-hard-drive-bios-geometries a list here https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hdtypes/hdtypes-3.html shows a  Phoenix 3.5 Award-486 BiOS listing the parameters correctly. The parameters not being on the drive itself would explain why the USB enclosure can't identify it.

Comment: Is replacing the floppy drive an option?

Comment: I don't have specific details, but I remember Conner drives in Compaqs of that era weren't strictly IDE compatible. They would only work with the Compaq HD controller

Comment: The diagnostic information displayed is just the partition table stored in the boot sector; not that useful on its own, other than to confirm the drive is accessible and partitioned correctly. I was hoping I could find the software somewhere, though…

Answer (score 11):

The USB enclosure is intended for much newer drives. It can't understand such an old drive with no logical block addressing (LBA) support.

The drive needs to be connected directly to motherboard IDE or PCI IDE adapter for better compatibility.

You can transfer files with many file transfer programs and cables, or network, and since your floppy drive is broken, there are a few programs that can be uploaded through serial cable between two computers.

Comment: IIRC [laplink and interlink](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14760/6868) was native to MS-DOS so there is a chance the old 386 has it on the drive already inside MS-DOS commands folder ... without the need to download anything

Comment: @Spektre LapLink is commercial software that did not come with MS-DOS. And it is PC-DOS 5.0 instead of MS-DOS, and InterLink came with MS-DOS 6 or later.

Comment: MS-DOS Kermit might work: there are [versions available](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/mskermit.html) for download and a [PDF](https://kermitproject.org/onlinebooks/kermitbook.pdf) with a BASIC bootstrap program (ch. 7, p. 191) so you can enjoy entering a program just like in the old days :-)

Comment: Here are many ways to bootstrap Kermit on DOS using a serial (RS-232) cable: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9762 . As soon as you have Kermit on DOS, and C-Kermit on Linux, you can send and receive files conveniently over the serial cable.

Comment: I've also found this tutorial for sending and receiving files over the serial cable between a PC running DOS and a PC running Windows 95+: https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/transfer/fastlynx33/fastlynx33_serial.htm . However, it uses commercial software you have to pay for.

Comment: @pts It appears equivalent to the (included with MS-DOS) INTERLNK/INTERSVR, including the bootstrapped client transfer.

Comment: @Sneftel The difference is with FastLynx and LapLink etc, you need both PCs to run a program to transfer files. Interlink allows you to map a drive on remote server as local drive, to normally copy/run/access files from server directly, like over a network.

Answer (score 8):

I never got the USB connection to work, those who thought it was at fault were correct.  I ultimately found an old tower running Windows 10 that had an unused EIDE connection, plugged the 40 wire IDE cable in and it was recognized. Robocopy and Copy would only copy the smaller files and that took hours.  With Gparted the whole drive was copied in 4 minutes.  It then turned out that in the 90's Conner drives were small and expensive and slow relative to the CPU so data was compressed on the fly as it was stored.  The stuff of interest is on a 100mb file STACKVOL.DSK and current efforts are centered on trying to unstack it.

Comment: If you have the disk image, you can mount it (or a backup) in a virtual machine and run it. Give the virtual machine a second drive large enough to copy the Stacker compressed files there, unless you find a tool to mount Stacker compressed volumes.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Those old Conner drives can be difficult. You can mark your response here as the answer, so it might help people in the future

Answer (score 0):

In practice: If you are an enthusiast that tends to end up in that situation frequently, building a dedicated "disk handling" machine can be a wise thing to do. Find the most compact and modern board (usually, that will mean a P3 or P4 era board) that still has a true (two channels supported!) floppy controller and a real IDE controller and put it in a case where the side panels are easy to take off. Boards that have real IDE, and also SATA, are optimal - you can put your OS disk on the SATA controller and have less chance of a bad IDE device hanging up the whole machine.

Set up with 32-bit Debian Linux, optionally also an actual DOS or old Windows system. Optimally, ALSO with a CD drive - some very early IDE drives that use automatic geometry translation tricks can be REALLY recalcitrant and might need trying several live CDs with older kernels....