# I have old hardware; what can I use it for?

Tags: hardware, hard-disk, ide

I have two old pieces of hardware: a DVD drive and a hard disk, both from 2004, which I would like to use.

I have a computer made for Windows 7, currently running Windows 98 which would probably run whatever is on those two items.

Here is the issue. The hard disk and DVD drive are both IDE-based, and no PC's from my house have IDE cables/ports. The only cable from the items that I have is the four-pin legacy power connector.

I will not throw away any of these items and I was thinking about buying an IDE cable and a SATA to IDE adapter but I also do not want to do that.

Is there really anything I *can* do?

Comment: You could always bedazzle them and use them as window props or even doorstops.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious although yes i could, i prefer to use them for something, NOT like that. not like the school i saw that used hard drivers as chair props.

Comment: You’re going to have to buy _some_ adapter, why do you say you don’t want SATA-IDE?

Comment: @JacobKrall i mean i could, just i was wondering if anyone had ideas, because i sure do not. unless of course im supposed to open up the hard disk and then switch the disks inside with another hard drive so i can access the contents, i know that wont work though.

Comment: Does the Win98 machine have any expansion slots? You could get an IDE controller. Does it have USB? You could get an IDE-USB adapter. Do you want to make your own, but slower, less reliable, and more expensive? Learn digital electronics! (/s)

Comment: @JacobKrall i have lots of paper clips, just i dont want too much smoke,

Comment: re-using old mechanical hard drives isn't a good idea, as they have a tendency to fail, this is guaranteed after a few years.

Comment: @Humancoder1123 but they are simply that. Props that outlived their original usage, ready to be put to a new purpose.

Comment: Double-check the motherboard, there most likely is a IDE connector hiding in a corner somewhere.

Comment: ok quick question, this question got closed for not being about retrocomputing, so old IDE hard-disks from 2004 isnt retro enough?

Comment: Closing questions like this is what makes for widespread memes about stackexchange moderator arrogance.

Comment: unscrew it, turn the disks into wind chimes, or turn it into a clock or make the head actuator into a speaker

Answer (score 9):

So, you need to translate the IDE interface to *something*. Since the controller on the hard drive can't just be easily swapped (can't just put the platters into some random SATA drive), your options are basically some kind of adapter.

Do note that I assume an IDE Drive that supports LBA addressing - I have no idea if any of them support CHS addressing, so if you have a drive from the 1980s/very early 90s, [things get more complicated](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26417/how-to-read-a-104-mb-conner-hard-drive-from-1990).

### An IDE-to-SATA Bridge that connects to the drive directly

I've used those way back in the day on Slot 1/Socket 7-era systems, and they worked pretty well. I don't remember if I used them on an optical drive, but this was the most elegant solution for a single drive.

They do make the drive longer and I don't know if the SATA connectors are in a standardized position, so using them in SATA Enclosures is probably not going to work.

Also note that IDE and SATA use different power connectors. Some bridges - like the one pictured - come with a little power adapter, but I've seen some others that didn't and required 4-Pin Molex power into the hard drive. In this case, you'd end up needing two power cables: One SATA one to power the board, and a Molex one to power the drive.

These bridges were made in both directions: There are ones that convert a SATA Drive to IDE, and ones that convert an IDE Drive to SATA - you want the latter, but a quick search on eBay shows a mix of the former and latter.

[image: IDE-SATA Bridge]

### A USB-to-IDE Adapter or Enclosure

These come in a variety of versions, for example as a simple adapter:

[image: USB-IDE Adapter]

The problem with those is that you need to provide a molex power cable somehow. Also, USB Adapters may require drivers on older systems (e.g., you will likely not be able to install MS-DOS or Windows 95 on such a drive)

There are more fancy enclosures with power bricks, but functionally they're the same.

[image: USB-IDE Enclosure]

### A PCI or PCI Express IDE Controller

We used those back in the day to add Ultra-ATA to old mainboards, and now we can use them to add it to new mainboards. They require running an IDE ribbon cable, so you also get the authentic feeling of running a big cable without impeding airflow. Good times.

I don't remember if driver support was needed in the OS for them, I believe they just worked even as boot drives if the BIOS of the machine was new enough.

[image: PCI IDE Controller]

[image: PCIe IDE Controller]

Comment: @Humancoder1123 Correct, the SATA/IDE bridge adapter handles all of that and would be my preferred choice. I don't know how easily they are available in 2023 - also make sure that it's the correct direction, because there are also adapters to turn a SATA Hard Drive into IDE.

Comment: @MichaelStum Both the "IDE drive on a SATA system" and the "SATA drive on an IDE system" versions of that board appear to still be readily available on eBay for around $5 CAD each.

Comment: @MichaelStum sorry for typing comment three times (something went wrong) but since sata has its own power connector, if i use the bridge, will i still have to use the legacy 4 pin power connector?

Comment: @Humancoder1123 look at the photo — the drive is powered from the board.

Comment: @Humancoder1123 Yeah, as Stephen said, this specific one comes with an adapter to power it from the board, but there are some adapter boards that don't do that and you'd need a 4 pin power connector. I've updated my answer.